# MyBatis Parameter Passing

Tags: mysql, spring, mybatis, spring-mybatis

I want to use a common query template to do filtering in myBatis-3. My template look something like this:

```
<sql id="filter">
    SELECT * FROM (${subquery}) LIMIT ${page}, 20
</sql>
```

The subquery placeholder can accept any query. I tried to pass the subquery as a parameter. But unfortunately this does not work, the subquery is empty. I wonder it’s possible the property’s value accept dynamic value?

```
<select
    id="find"
    parameterType="some.page"
    resultMap="map">
    <include refid="some.namespace.filter">
        <property name="subquery" value="${subquery}"/>
        <property name="page" value="#{page}"/>
    </include>
</select>

<sql id="subquery">
    SELECT * FROM test_table ORDER BY id
</sql>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just change another way to do this? I don't think the feature you've said is supported by `MyBatis`, maybe you can do it like following;

```
<select
    id="find"
    parameterType="some.page"
    resultMap="map">
    SELECT * FROM (<include refid="subquery">) t LIMIT ${page}, 20
</select>

<sql id="subquery">
    SELECT * FROM test_table ORDER BY id
</sql>
```

Comment: Ya, I know this way can achieve the same result. I wanted to use a common template because I don't want to keep repeating this `SELECT * FROM (${subquery}) LIMIT ${page}, 20`

Comment: @user3502676 With my limited knowledge, `Mybatis` does not support the feature you mentioned as so far; and even if `Mybatis` support this, you're no need to repeat this quite simple query `SELECT * FROM (${subquery}) LIMIT ${page}, 20`, but you have to repeat this not too short inlclude`<include refid="some.namespace.filter"><property name="subquery" value="${subquery}"/><property name="page" value="#{page}"/></include>`, doesn't it?